# How to parse only required tables from HTML page and eport results in to .CSV file using JAVA?

Tags: java

I have an .html page in my folder. And it has 38 tables with different rows in it. My requirement is, using a java program, where i can select only tables 1,12,36,37 and read their data. then with that resulted data, i need to produce a .csv file. Is it possible? any specific library? I have googled, but i am getting for only one table parsing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) to parse HTML and extract the required data. Then write to CSV format which is fairly easy without any library but you may look into [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

Comment: Thank you Nishant. Is it possible to avoid other html content like images and select only required data parsing using jsoup?

Comment: yes. Learn more about extracting data using jSoup here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple HTML parsers that could help you, and the most of them are opensource.

You could use this one for example: [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), I've used it in several projects with good results.
The idea is that you parse your HTML and you could extract by ID or by HTML tag (table) the content you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Java XPath library to query documents like xml and html. In XPath, you can get a subset of your XML document according to certain predicates.
Have a look: [Java XPath tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-javaxpathapi/index.html/) and [XPath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/)